# Add a css class to the element in template

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

How can I add a CSS class to the element in the template?

for example, I want to add a CSS class to this element

```
<div class="page-wrapper example">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add Custom Css class to the existing div element to the magento you need follow the below mentioned procedure.

add

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" htmlClass="page-wrapper example"/>
```

in your custom theme default.xml layout file

Comment: We should add htmlTag if the html element doesn't exist: <container name="custom_head" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container"> otherwise the error could appear. "HTML ID or class will not have effect, if HTML tag is not specified."

Answer (score 0):

Please add your css to vendor/module/frontend/web/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is add your custom css File:

If you have already a custom theme (inherited from Luma) i would suggest to place it in the folder "Magento_Theme\web\css\custom.css"
and add your css there

then you want to include your css in the pages that you want,
if you need it in the whole site i suggest to declare it in:

"Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml"
inside it:

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom.css" />
```

Instead if you dont have a custom template, you'll have to create a file in:

```
vendor\module\view\frontend\layout\default_head_blocks.xml
```

inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/custom.css" />
</head>
</page>
```

And your css in:

Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\css\custom.css